# Heroku webhook for when application or dyno crashes. Does it exist?

Tags: heroku

We have several microservices in heroku, every now and them, any of them can crash, we know why, we can look at logs and solve the issue.

But I've been looking in heroku documentation without much success, if there's a way of heroku letting me know that an application or a dyno crashed?

Is there any event I can configure, like heroku pinging an URL, maybe with the name of the app? or something of that sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a [Logging AddOn](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging) to manage/view your logs in a Log Aggregator that offers features like that: for example in Papertrail you can define queries (i.e. message includes `ERROR`) that send an email when they find some results (configuring also how often, etc..)

Comment: Read the papertrail documentation and it seems like this is exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, I have emails for every message that has the ERROR prefix (or something like), reach out if you are issues configuring it. Good luck.